# JavaScript event object?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I was told that an 'event object' gets passed as a parameter to the function in the program below. What would an example of an 'event object' be? Is it, for example, the `<p>` element if you clicked on a `<p>` or `<html>` if you clicked on `<html>`, or is the event object the actual 'click'?

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
console.log(e.target.nodeName);
},false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's roughly the actual click.  See the thorough MDC documentation for [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) and [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event/UIEvent/MouseEvent).  You can get the target element from [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target).

Comment: Also, you can use `console.log(e)` to take a peek at what you got.

Answer (score 0):

in html code you can use by example:

```
<input type="text" onchange="show(this)" />

<script>
  show(e) {alert(e.value);}
</script>
```

best regards!